# Infer type from return value with JSDoc

Tags: jsdoc

What is the correct way to assign type from a functions return type?

```js
async function getFood(){
  const food = await {fruit: 'banana', qty: 3}
  return food
}

/** 
 * made up syntax
 * @type {returnOf getFood} 
 * */
let doesntWork;

/** @type {{fruit: string, qty: number}} */
let worksButNoInferring

let worksButRequiresCallingFunction = getFood()
```

As evidenced by VSCode, the return type is available. I just don't know how to get it without calling the function.

[image]

Comment: Duplicite of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63615171/how-to-properly-get-inferred-types-of-returned-values-in-a-wrapper-function-with ?

Comment: @ObscurusGrassator TBH I don't think what I'm asking for is possible. Templates can alleviate some situations, but actual inference of function returns I don't think is possible with JSDoc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is probably not according to the JSDoc specification, but VS Code supports Typescript syntax in JSDoc.

```ts
async function getFood(){
    const food = await {fruit: 'banana', qty: 3}
    return food
}

/** @type { typeof getFood extends (...args: any[]) => infer U ? U : any } */
let test;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-dev.20210504#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwOYFNkBi66AJgBQCUA3gLABQMMUmIy8xJMAvDMAO7BUbKnABOCIQC4YAcgBGwCIuAyANDACOyMNIDMAX3qNR+BKKxwO9Q3XraADrhjJcrbs7CP0cHPiKkYXAAPFwgSEBgyADoY4FFsEGlFMABtAF0KbgA+GFQIOFxRGABVGAB+EpgkiDAAbnogA)

Comment: That goes way over my head, but it works. 